# Three.js Applying Repeated Texture to JSON Scene Object

Tags: three.js

I have a basic json scene exported from the three.js/editor. I want to add a repeated texture wrap to an object in this scene but I do not know how to do so since the only examples I have found add the wrap in the creation of the object.

I have already tried accessing the texture and giving it a wrap, but I think I might need to add a texture to the object from the JavaScript then declare the texture wrap instead of trying to add it to an already loaded texture.

```
<script>
    var camera, scene, renderer;
    var mesh;
    init();
    animate();
    function init() {
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
        camera.position.z = 400;
        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        var objectLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();

        objectLoader.load( "models/cube.json", function ( obj ) {

            scene.add( obj )

            obj.traverse(function(child) {
                if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                    child.castShadow = true;
                    child.receiveShadow = true;
                }
            });

                obj.name = "cube";
                obj.position.set(0,0,0);
                obj.scale.set(200,200,200);
            });

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            //
            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            while (scene.getObjectByName('Box 1')){
                var texture = scene.getObjectByName('Box 1').material;
                texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                texture.repeat.set( 2, 2 );
            }
        }
        function onWindowResize() {
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        }
        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            if (scene.getObjectByName('Box 1')  ){
                scene.getObjectByName('Box 1').material.map.offset.x += 0.001;
            }           
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the wrap and repeat properties of the texture/map and not of the material. Docs also say it's important to set `needsUpdate` to true, if wrap settings changed. And you are trying to set the properties before the json is loaded (in a while loop?). You should do it within the `load` callback.

```js
objectLoader.load( "models/cube.json", function ( obj ) {

    scene.add( obj )

    obj.traverse(function(child) {
        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
            child.castShadow = true;
            child.receiveShadow = true;
        }
    });

    obj.name = "cube";
    obj.position.set(0,0,0);
    obj.scale.set(200,200,200);

    var box1 = scene.getObjectByName('Box 1');
    if (box1) {
        var texture = box1.material.map;
        texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
        texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
        texture.repeat.set( 2, 2 );
        texture.needsUpdate = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I think I have hit this bit of code a couple of times but my issue was not calling it in the load callback since the scene creation is only called once. It was skipping my if statement since the scene hadn't loaded then jumping into the animate function so my code was never even being touched.